vcpkg:mongo-c-driver[openssl]:arm64-ios-release build failure
build on macos14 with github actions.
I don’t know why it failed to compile. I tried it in the actions of github. I haven’t modified anything else and vcpkg is also the latest.
yml code is:
name: ios build workflows

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main

permissions:
  contents: read
  
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - os: macos-14
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout main repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: brew install
        run: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
        
      - name: vcpkg dependency repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: microsoft/vcpkg
          path: vcpkg              
          
      - name: vcpkg install
        run: |
            brew install cmake ninja pkg-config autoconf
            cd vcpkg
            ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
            ./vcpkg install 'mongo-c-driver[openssl]:arm64-ios-release'


and config-arm64-ios-release-rel-out.log is:
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode_15.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
cat: /Users/runner/vcpkg/buildtrees/mongo-c-driver/config-arm64-ios-release-rel-out.log: No such file or directory
-- Looking for a CXX compiler
-- Looking for a CXX compiler - /Applications/Xcode_15.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode_15.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_LLD_LINKER_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_LLD_LINKER_SUPPORT - Failed
-- Searching for libbson CMake packages
-- libbson found version "1.29.1"
-- disabling test-libmongoc since using system libbson
-- Python3 was not found, so test fixtures will not be defined
-- Looking for sched_getcpu
-- Looking for sched_getcpu - not found
-- libmongoc version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.29.1
-- Searching for zlib CMake packages
-- Found ZLIB: /Users/runner/work/test/test/vcpkg/installed/arm64-ios-release/lib/libz.a (found version "1.3.1")
--    zlib found version "1.3.1"
--    zlib include path "/Users/runner/work/test/test/vcpkg/installed/arm64-ios-release/include"
--    zlib libraries "/Users/runner/work/test/test/vcpkg/installed/arm64-ios-release/lib/libz.a"
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h - found
-- Found OpenSSL: /Users/runner/work/test/test/vcpkg/installed/arm64-ios-release/lib/libcrypto.a (found version "3.4.0")
-- libmongoc TLS : OpenSSL
-- Looking for ASN1_STRING_get0_data
-- Looking for ASN1_STRING_get0_data - found
-- Using SASL backend : OFF
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of socklen_t
-- Check size of socklen_t - done
-- Looking for res_nsearch
-- Looking for res_nsearch - not found
-- Looking for res_search
-- Looking for res_search - not found
-- Looking for res_ndestroy
-- Looking for res_ndestroy - not found
-- Looking for res_nclose
-- Looking for res_nclose - not found
-- Looking for res_nsearch
-- Looking for res_nsearch - not found
-- Looking for res_search
-- Looking for res_search - not found
-- Looking for res_ndestroy
-- Looking for res_ndestroy - not found
-- Looking for res_nclose
-- Looking for res_nclose - not found
-- Detected parameters: accept (int, struct sockaddr *, socklen_t *)
-- Performing Test MONGOC_HAVE_SS_FAMILY
-- Performing Test MONGOC_HAVE_SS_FAMILY - Success
-- SASL disabled
-- Adding -fPIC to compilation of mongoc_static components
-- Building with MONGODB-AWS auth support
-- Build files generated for:
--  build system: Ninja
-- The following features have been enabled:

 * TLS, for secure network communication (OpenSSL)
 * Cryptography, cryptographic primitives (OpenSSL)
 * AWS Authentication, authenticate with MongoDB servers using credentials from AWS instance metadata

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * SASL Authentication, authenticate with MongoDB servers using SASL: “Simple Authentication and Security Layer” (OFF)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Is res_search not found because of this? What kind of error is this? Or is it because the ios version is not supported?
